# How to host ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application on IIS as a development mode

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

How to host an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application on IIS as a development mode? I don't want to publish the application, I just want to use it as localhost deploy and when I make some changes and build the application, the new changes should show up on localhost.

I want to host it as a local for debugging.

Note:- I don't want to run the project by press F5 for "start debugging".

see the screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SisqN.png

Comment: Do you *need* to run on IIS? The default, IISExpress also works fine for debugging

Comment: You need Visual Studio, https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support

Comment: Yes, I also agree with the document content mentioned by Lex Li. Just create and configure the IIS launch profile according to your own needs. So I'm wondering if there are any updates on this issue?

Comment: @XudongPeng yes i already impliment that but still i have run it by clicking on Run button or F5, I just want one thing to host website on localhost(IIS) in my machine, when ever i want to see the website i just type "http://localhost/mywebiste" I can see the website I don't have to open the visual studio and run the website from visual studio. On same time if i want to work on this webiste I just open visual studio made some new changes on that website and build that project that it. new changes automatically reflected on the website I have no need to publish website or some change on iis.

Comment: If this is the case, I'm afraid I can't find such a configuration in Visual Studio, and perhaps other community members can provide another solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your visual studio has some issues but when you start your project in visual studio, it will start on localhost

but check these

please right click on your starter project and choose "set as start project"
[image]

then run your project, you can use F5 for "start debugging" or ctrl+F5 for "start without debugging"

[image]

Comment: I know this But this is not the solution for my question

Answer (score -1):

If you want to deploy files to a local IIS on each build, use a Post Build task in VS to execute a batch file after each build. In that batch file you could stop the IIS site (or create a app_offline.html), copy your files to the IIS webroot, then restart the app (or delete the app_offline.html). Stopping/Starting the site is optional but will avoid various issues and ensure your always looking at the latest version.

NOTE: Doing it this way you loose the integration with the VS debugger. I also assume IIS is installed with all required components.

See docs:

- Microsoft docs for [pre/postbuild scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2022)
- Microsoft docs for [App_Offline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-8.0) OR [AppCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) for starting/stopping IIS from a batch file

Comment: I don't want to copy and past in each change. I already impliment pre/postbuild in visual studio. In asp mvc 4 i implement it (create a similar environment on my local as on the server but i did it without publish i create a website on iis and my physical path is my root of the project on mvc4 or 5 it's working fine) but in asp mvc core (.Net 8) it's not working

Comment: See the link in the comment by Lex Li under the question. No need to do this complex build task, VS can both run and debug a site running under IIS